# Prevent AdSense from showing a smaller ad centered in a 970x250 horizontal banner

Tags: google-adsense, advertising

I've replaced a static 728x90 AdSense ad on my site with the responsive code, and set it up so that a 970x250 can serve.

With the code below, I get 970x250 serving just fine, but often, a centered 300x250 appears which doesn't look right.

If I utilise the following code to block 300x250, it also blocks 970x250 which does not seem to be considered in the "horizontal" family.

```
data-ad-format="horizontal"
```

How can I ensure that a 970x250 and other horizontal banners are allowed.

```
<style>
.google_responsive_bb {width: 320px;height: 100px;}
@media(min-width: 500px) {.google_responsive_bb{width:336px;height:280px;}}
@media(min-width: 970px) {.google_responsive_bb{width:970px;height:250px;}}
</style>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- google_responsive_bb -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle google_responsive_bb"
     style="display:inline-block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
     data-ad-slot="XXXXXXXXXXXXX"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```